# Logo is expanding my bootstrap navbar on my webpage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, png, graphical-logo

I have created a logo in .png format and the current dimensions are 200x200PNG(32-bit color),I am using anchor/img html tags to embed this logo in my navbar section of my webpage. The issue is, if I add css of height: 3rem; the logo appears as super tiny in the upper left hand corner. If I remove all styling and just have the anchor/img tag in my div that contains my bootstrap nav, the logo appears as a decent size but then my navbar assumes the height of my logo, causing my navbar to expand down the page way more than I want it to. How do I get my logo to appear as a readable/distinguishable size while keeping my navbar at a normal height?

CSS and HTMLpertaining to nav

```
.navbar{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.09rem;
    background: rgba(35, 36, 44, 0.6) !important;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}

.navbar-brand img{
    height: 3rem;
}

.navbar-nav li{
    padding-right: .7rem;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link{
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 0.8rem;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover{
    color: #edadbf;
}


 <!--HTML-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img id="diy3" src="img/diy3.png"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarResponsive">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="navitem">
                    <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navitem">
                    <a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navitem">
                    <a href="#projects" class="nav-link">Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navitem">
                    <a href="#clients" class="nav-link">Clients</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navitem">
                    <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--End Navbar-->
```

Comment: See this: [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#brand](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#brand)

Comment: @RobMoll the link was not helpful. Which part was supposed to standout?

Comment: This part: _Adding images to the .navbar-brand will likely always require custom styles or utilities to properly size. Here are some examples to demonstrate._

Comment: Ahh yes I saw that so now I am fiddling with different css stylings. Thanks for the direction. I just thought maybe there was a more uniform answer since logos.png are so common.